# Does the phrasal verb "stare down" imply that you are trying to intimidate?

Tags: definition

Does it? What should you say if you just want to say you're staring without looking away without wanting to intimidate the person you are staring?

I found the following definition and I thought it implied the intention of intimidating:

[stare someone down/out] to look at someone for so long that they have to look away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that your assumption is correct: the phrasal verb *stare down* is indeed  used when there is some kind of intimidation going on.

If you want to talk about someone staring without any kind of standoff or intimidation, you could simply use *stare **at***, instead of *stare **down***. If you are casting a more probing look, where you are trying to study something carefully, you can also use *stare **into***. Lovers generally stare *into* each others' eyes, not merely *at* each others' eyes.

If two people are staring at each other, each hoping to outlast the other, but it's simply a playful game rather than opposing glares of intimidation, that is sometimes called a *blinking contest* (or *staring contest*).

Answer (score 0):

It is the "down" that makes "stare down" intimidating.

You can just say "stare", which can mean looking in surprise or in disbelief.
There is also the verb **gaze**

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gaze) has this definition:

> Look steadily and intently, especially in admiration, surprise, or
>   thought.

which you can use without any sense of intimidation.

Comment: any phrasal verb?

Comment: @puffofsmoke If you mean "can you separate any phrasal verb in this way and keep the same meaning?" Then the answer is *no*. In fact, you cannot even separate the phrasal verb "stare down" in this way. "Stare down" as a phrasal verb has a particular meaning that is not expressed by "stare".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "stare down" as phrasal verb implies intimidation or a challenge. (In other contexts, the words "stare down" be adjacent but not used as a phrasal verb, such as "Why do you stare down the road whenever I ask you a question?")

You can use different prepositions to imply different types of staring. "Stare at" does not imply intimidation. You can also use "stare through", which usually means that someone is looking in the direction of something but seemingly not paying attention to it. You can also forgo the preposition and just "stare".